# How to treat java package as a File folder?

Tags: java, file, directory, scripting, package

I want to be able to iterate through a package of files as if the package were a folder.

Something like the below (scripts being the java package):

```
        File scriptFolder = new File("scripts").getAbsoluteFile();
```

The packages appear are not being treated like folders. If I hardcode the path `C:\Users\...\project_folder\...\scripts` the `File.isFile()` method returns false for the package. If I do  `new File (C:\Users\...\project_folder\...\scripts\script).isFile()` I get true.

I want to get a File of the folder so I can get a list of the files in the folder and iterate through it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Java packages are folders, there is nothing special about them.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question and state what exactly you are trying to achieve here. If you would like to access a non java file from your packages I have an answer for you.

Comment: is your package inside a jar/war? or just on the filesystem? cause a package in Java is just like @meskobalazs says nothing more than a directory. so if it's just a package on the filesystem then you can access them just like other directories. If they are in a jar, then it depends on if they are loaded into the classpath or not on how you can access the files

Comment: @meskobalazs They are not being treated like folders. If I hardcode the path `C:\Users\...\project_folder\...\scripts` the `File.isFile()` method returns false for the package. If I do  `new File (C:\Users\...\project_folder\...\scripts\script).isFile()` I get true

Comment: @biG-AdR please see OP

Comment: doesn't seem to change the perspective. ../scripts/ is a folder containing the file script. so the package scripts is just a folder, what is verified in your isFile()==false (as it is a directory) your ../scripts/script returns true, so that's your file inside your package/directory

Comment: `new File (C:\Users\...\project_folder\...\scripts\script` creates a new file, *not a directory*.

Comment: Please check the result of new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();. This will be your "working directory". You can then append the rest of the path there: String scriptsfolder = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath() + "/src/com/example/scripts"; Obviously replace the / with File.separator for cross-platform. Hope this helps. Note that this will not work for JAR packaged applications.

Answer (score 1):

The `.isFile()` method returns true only if you are referencing a plain jane normal file. If you're referencing a directory, it'd return false. Try `.isDirectory()` or possibly `.exists()`.

Or don't; there's no real need:

```
File[] filesInDir = new File("C:\\Users\\....\\scripts").listFiles();
if (filesInDir == null) {
    // this means it wasn't a directory or didn't exist or isn't readable
} else {
    for (File child : filesInDir) {
        // called for each file in dir
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official javadocs say this about [`File#isFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()):

> Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a normal file. A file is *normal* if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. Any non-directory file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file.

You can check if it is a directory with [`File#isDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()), then if it is, you can list its contents with [`File#listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()).

Comment: Given the package is a directory, how can i get the relative path of it? .getAbsoluteFile() and .getAbsolutePath() don't appear to work when just given the name of the package

Comment: Relative in regards to what?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something in your question C:\Users...\project_folder...\scripts is a directory so isFile() will return false because it is not a file.

Comment: That answers part of my question - how do I treat the directory as a folder?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, it is a folder. A directory is a folder.